# How can I connect to the network of an IP camera from inside a Docker Container?

Tags: docker, networking, camera, ip, share

I have a camera that can be connected to my Windows PC through an Ethernet cable, or with an Ethernet to USB adapter. When connected, the PC has a new network interface which is the network where the camera can be found.
I have a python script that searches for cameras in all network interfaces, and when I run it on my PC, it works because it finds the network interface and the camera.
However, when I run this script as a Docker container with my Dockerfile, it does not work because the docker container (I suppose) does not have this network interface so it doesn't find the camera.
How can I share the interface to the container so it finds the camera?

I tried creating bridge networks, but I couldn't connect them to the network created by the camera.
I also looked into connecting the camera to the router and use port forwarding, but it wasn't possible.
I also tried sharing the adapter device using --device but with Windows it caused problems.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I’m trying to solve a similar problem using spinnaker to a FLIR camera.

Comment: @pfa I was also using this with Spinnaker with a FLIR camera. My solution was running the container with --network=host and -v /dev:/dev, sharing the devices on my host (I had to switch to Ubuntu) to my container. Ideally I would only share the network adapter that the camera needs but I was pressed for time so I went all out.